# Oracle SQL help regarding fetching a distinct balance

Tags: sql, oracle

select pdat,ac_no, bal from dummy_table;

```
PDATE     | AC_NO | BAL
14/02/2012| abcd  | 1200
15/02/2012| abcd  | 1300
29/02/2012| abcd  | 1300
```

My question is how can I make the result set to fetch

```
PDATE     | AC_NO | BAL
14/02/2012| abcd  | 1200
29/02/2012| abcd  | 1300
```

that is maximum date of the same balance?

I have tried using MAX and Distinct in my ORACLE query, but they don't work.

Comment: Just to be sure, you don't want to see balance changes, just "the last time I had that balance"? Ie 1200 balance today, 1100 yesterday and 1200 the day before that, you don't want to see the value 2 days ago since you have the same balance today?

Comment: I have to check balance change, but if the balance was same from 15th feb to 23rd feb, ill have to fetch the row with 23rd feb

Comment: So in my example, you'd want 3 rows as a result?

Comment: Yes 3 rows, every balance change with the date it has changed on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select max(pdate) as pdate,
       ac_no,
       bal
from your_table
group by ac_no, bal
```

Comment: @nightWatcher I think you need to be a bit clearer. Wrong result? Does not run? What does it return that shouldn't show up? A quick test  (with "your_table" replaced with "dummy_table") on the test data you provided seems to return exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

So it seems to me your problem could be re-stated like this:

> Whenever there is a group of consecutive rows with the same `AC_NO` and `BAL`, return only the last one of them, where both *consecutive* and *last* imply *as ordered by `PDATE`*.

Here's how I would approach this problem in SQL Server:

```
SELECT
  MAX(PDATE) AS PDATE,
  AC_NO,
  BAL
FROM (
  SELECT
    YourTable.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AC_NO      ORDER BY PDATE) -
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AC_NO, BAL ORDER BY PDATE) AS grp
  FROM YourTable
) s
GROUP BY
  AC_NO,
  BAL,
  grp
ORDER BY
  AC_NO,
  MAX(PDATE)
;
```

Basically, the query uses double ranking to determine groups of consecutive rows where `AC_NO` and `BAL` are identical. Every such group thus receives an additional attribute which, together with `AC_NO` and `BAL`, uniquely identifies the group, and then you only need to use these three columns to group the rows and get `MAX(PDATE)`.

I was expecting this to work in Oracle just [as well as it did in SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f33cc/1). However, when testing the query in Oracle at SQL Fiddle, [I got this error](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85cb0/2):

```
ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply
```

Would be great if someone experienced in Oracle commented on it with regard to this particular query. Meanwhile, here's an alternative ([which does work in Oracle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85cb0/5)), where grouping is replaced with one more round of ranking + retrieval of the top-ranked rows:

```
SELECT
  PDATE,
  AC_NO,
  BAL
FROM (
  SELECT
    PDATE,
    AC_NO,
    BAL,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AC_NO, BAL, grp ORDER BY PDATE DESC) AS rnk
  FROM (
    SELECT
      PDATE,
      AC_NO,
      BAL,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AC_NO      ORDER BY PDATE) -
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AC_NO, BAL ORDER BY PDATE) AS grp
    FROM YourTable
  ) s
) s
WHERE rnk = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select max(pdate),
       ac_no,
       bal
from dummy_table
group by ac_no, bal;
```